# Update table depending on value without overlapping field names

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update, case

I have two tables:

```
Table A with system values
------------------------
id  |  val_1  |  val_2 |
------------------------
 1  |   11    |   22   |
------------------------

Table B with user values
-----------------------
uid  |  set  |  val_3 |
-----------------------
 21  |   1   |   11   |
-----------------------
 68  |   2   |   22   |
-----------------------
 83  |   1   |   11   |
-----------------------
```

I'd like to update **val_3** in Table B with the values of **val_1** and **val_2** of Table A, according to the values of **set** in Table B.

So if I change: Table A val_1 => 333, Table A val_2 => 666, the update query changes Table B to:

---

```
uid  |  set  |  val 3 |
-----------------------
 21  |   1   |   333  |
-----------------------
 68  |   2   |   666  |
-----------------------
 83  |   1   |   333  |
-----------------------
```

**Is this possible in one query?**
Now I do:

```
$result=$mysql->query('SELECT val1,val2 from TABLE A WHERE id=1');
UPDATE TABLE B set val3=$result[0] WHERE set=1
UPDATE TABLE B set val3=$result[1] WHERE set=2
```

Maybe I could do a `CASE WHEN` but I don't know how to do it without a corresponding row value for Table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an update using a JOIN:-

```
UPDATE TableB
CROSS JOIN TableA
SET TableB.val_3 = CASE WHEN TableB.`set` = 1 THEN TableA.val_1 ELSE TableB.`set` = 2 THEN TableA.val_2 END
WHERE TableA.id=1
AND TableB.`set` IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Works nice! Now I have another problem. I have two working solutions: yours and the one from @Aziz Shaikh. And as a mysql noob, which one is the best? :-)

Comment: His requires sub queries. These may perform badly when the amount of data increases greatly (ie, MySQL gets one set of results and then internally for each row it has to go and perform another query), but his solution may also be easier to read for people with less experience of SQL.

Comment: I was just thinking: does @Aziz Shaikhs solution requires MySQL to lookup the value of val1/val2 every time, and yours not. So I'm correct. Thanks for explaining and the answer!

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL might manage to optimise away the need to look up each value individually but I wouldn't be certain of it. If you modify the queries to be SELECT statements instead then you can use EXPLAIN on them to check the differences (eg EXPLAIN SELECT CASE WHEN TableB.`set` = 1 THEN TableA.val_1 ELSE TableB.`set` = 2 THEN TableA.val_2 END
FROM TableB
CROSS JOIN TableA
WHERE TableA.id=1
AND TableB.`set` IN (1,2) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableB
SET val3 = 
   CASE set
     WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT val1 FROM TableA WHERE id=1)
     WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT val2 FROM TableA WHERE id=1)
   END
```

Comment: Works nice! Now I have another problem. I have two working solutions: yours and the one from @Kickstart. And as a mysql noob, which one is the best? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE Table_B
   SET val_3 = 
   CASE set
   WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT val_1 FROM Table_A WHERE id=1)
   WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT val_2 FROM Table_A WHERE id=1)
   END
```

Comment: The value of `val_3` is depending on the value `set`. See @Aziz Shaikh's answer above.

Comment: this case check val_3, if it is 11 then set your value from table A of column val_1 , same for 22

Comment: It is correct if val_3 is always 11 or 22, but it can be anything, depending on the values of val_1 and val_2

Comment: ok then you need to do this ,, updated ans similar to Mr. Aziz Shaikh